# Encoding problems on MacOS X with file generated in iOS

Tags: ios, macos, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem: generate .txt file within iOS, the file may contain Unicode characters, store it in UTF-8 and so on. When I get this file to MacOS X I get garbage on this special characters. The funny thing is that it I get it on 10.7.X (Lion) it opens just fine. The problem is 10.6.8 and TextEdit, another editors (SublimeText 2, for e.g.) open well.
Its not a particular computer, happens on any Snow Leopard I tested so far.

I write the file this way:

```
//correctString = [NSString stringWithCString:[correctString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
[correctString writeToFile:destFileText atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];
```

(actually tried all possible combinations)

Any idea ?

**Edit**: the issue has been resolved with some of the 10.6.8 updates

Comment: Can you make the file available on Dropbox?

Comment: Do you include the out commented line when you test? that one should not be needed and looks a bit broken, decodes UTF-16 as UTF-8.

Comment: the commented line is one of the attempts to get it work.
here is one of the test files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwwadm867zt22ay/2012-07-10-17-56-04.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`NSUTF8StringEncoding`

instead of NSUnicodeStringEncoding.

Comment: I tried all the combinations NSUTF8StringEncoding, NSUTF16StringEncoding, etc. The result is that the garbage varies, but   still there.

Comment: What is the string you're trying to write?

Comment: For example, these will result in garbage: €áóú· , (tm), (c) , etc.